# How to link data of a existing website to a mobile application which I am going to develop

Tags: android, mobile, web

i am developing a supermarket shopping mobile application.so I want to get supermarket's item prices and discount offers details up to date to the mobile application i am going to develop . Currently the supermarket I have chosen has their own website and all item prices and discount details are available up to date in their website. I want to use that data to my mobile application.
If the supermarket did change a price the new price should be updated in my mobile application as well.

Can we do this through linkq?
Could you suggest me an approach to do this?

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Write APIs using the existing database to interact with the app.

Comment: Use a `PHP` server using `JSON` to get data from app on Android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a research on [client-server architecture](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Client-server). Your server should parse supermarket's price list in a period.(once a week or something). When the server detects an update on the list. It should notify the clients which are mobile apps in this case.

Have fun!

Comment: I want to get an update as soon as a change done in website? is it possible?

Comment: It depends how regular you check the website's price list. If you catch the updates you can notify your users. That means you must check the websites all the time unless you have not notified by supermarket's website. Parsing a website all the time is costly operation. Also, legal issues should be considered before parsing a website.

Comment: If the supermarket has an API for it, you can use the data that API provides. However, in general these APIs limit your data usage. You should read API constraints for your usage.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps.

1) First of all get API of website(this API will be lying on server).

2) Follow a tutorial of RecyclerView and RecyclerView.onItemTouchListener.

3) Follow a good tutorial of Volley library of Android. It is easy to use and efficient. This library will provide API data as a JSONObject or JSONArrayObject as per your need.

4) From that Object you can get data into any of Collection (like ArrayList) as per your need.

5) Using that Collection you can set data to RecyclerView items.

6) For updating latest info of products. you and your team partners will have to make some logic. you can do this by app or you can also do some coding at server side to achinve this.